# Collection change Events in Observable dictionarys

Tags: c#, winforms, dictionary, observable

ok. First i connect to API. Add key/values to observable dictionary. Update item values every 10 seconds. Bind to list. This part I'm ok with. My understanding so far is if a key/value is added or remove the binded list automatically updates. But it doesn't. What im doing is aading:

```
public void priceData()
{
//backprice
listBox1.DataSource = new 
BindingSource(RunnersRacingNowDetail.racingDictionary.Values, null);
listBox1.DisplayMember = "backPrice";
}
```

Then using a timer to fire this method every 5 seconds, which works. I dont know how to fire the collection change event.

Comment: Please provide a [complete example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: `listBox1.DisplayMember = "backPrice";`? Add the Dictionary values to a `BindingList`. The `ObservableDictionary` origin should also be described...